# Custom command not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

In my XAML I have this:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Help"
   CanExecute="HelpCanExecute"
   Executed="HelpExecuted" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>

<MenuItem Header="Help" Command="Help" />
```

This works fine. So when I click the context menu, HelpExecuted() gets called.

Now I want to do the same again except use a custom command instead of the Help command. So what I do is:

```
public RoutedCommand MyCustomCommand = new RoutedCommand();
```

and change my XAML to:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="MyCustomCommand"
   CanExecute="HelpCanExecute"
   Executed="HelpExecuted" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>

<MenuItem Header="Help" Command="MyCustomCommand" />
```

But i get the error: Cannot convert string 'MyCustomCommand' in attribute 'Command' to object of type 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand'. CommandConverter cannot convert from System.String.

What am I missing here? And please note that I want to do it all in XAML, i.e. don't want to use CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(MyCustomCommand....

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Oops, sorry, was a bit fast to post my original answer. I now see that the problem is not with the type but with the CommandBinding. You need to use a markup extension to resolve the command name. I usually make my commands static in their declaration like this:

```
namespace MyApp.Commands
{
    public class MyApplicationCommands
    {
        public static RoutedUICommand MyCustomCommand 
                               = new RoutedUICommand("My custom command", 
                                                     "MyCustomCommand", 
                                                     typeof(MyApplicationCommands));
    }
}
```

And in the XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="..."
             ...
             xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:MyApp.Commands">
...
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static commands:MyApplicationCommands.MyCustomCommand}"
    CanExecute="HelpCanExecute"
    Executed="HelpExecuted" />
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

You need to bring in the namespace of the containing class by using xmlns. I called it 'commands' in my example above.

**Original post below:**

Try changing the type of the command to RoutedUICommand. The constructor is a bit different:

```
public RoutedUICommand MyCustomCommand 
             = new RoutedUICommand("Description", "Name", typeof(ContainingClass));
```

Comment: I updated my post, please see if that solves your problem. :-)

Comment: XStatic is redundant (at least as of .Net 4) and the code code be changed to 'Command="commands:MyApplicationCommands.MyCustomCommand"'

Comment: Maybe, but I just added x:Static in and the error in the window which adds the control reference went away and the control renders now. (commandconverter cannot convert from system.string, .net 4)