# CommandConverter cannot convert from System.String in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have strange error in WPF using .NET Framework 4.5

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ImportExcelCmd" CanExecute="ImportExcelCmd_CanExecute" Executed="ImportExcelCmd_Executed"></CommandBinding>
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="I" Modifiers="Control" Command="ImportExcelCmd"></KeyBinding>
</Window.InputBindings>
```

I receive an error that `CommandConverter cannot convert from System.String`

Where is my mistake ?

I have another binding to a ListView, like:

```
<ListView.CommandBindings>
     <CommandBinding Command="Delete" CanExecute="Delete_CanExecute" Executed="Delete_Executed"></CommandBinding>
</ListView.CommandBindings>
<ListView.InputBindings>
      <KeyBinding Key="Delete" Command="Delete"></KeyBinding>
</ListView.InputBindings>
```

and it works.

Comment: `Delete` is used in the following context: `<Button Command="Delete"></Button>`. Now I have issue with ImportExcelCmd

Comment: Why not bind the command to your viewmodel?

Comment: Now I understand to create custom command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to use **`Custom Routed commands`**, you to use more verbose definition.

Declare the routed command as `static` in class and then use it in XAML using **`x:Static`**.
You can refer to the answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4347233/632337).

---

For the sake of completeness of the answer, I am posting the relevant code from the answer here:

```
namespace MyApp.Commands
{
    public class MyApplicationCommands
    {
        public static RoutedUICommand ImportExcelCmd 
                            = new RoutedUICommand("Import excel command", 
                                                  "ImportExcelCmd", 
                                                  typeof(MyApplicationCommands));
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="..."
             ...
             xmlns:commands="clr-namespace:MyApp.Commands">
...
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding
            Command="{x:Static commands:MyApplicationCommands.ImportExcelCmd}"
            CanExecute="ImportExcelCmd_CanExecute"
            Executed="ImportExcelCmd_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Comment: That why with "DElete" command works and "ImportExcelCmd" didn't ? Ok, I have to create custom binding.

Comment: `Delete` works because that's default application command and not custom command. For custom command you to use like I mentioned in answer.

Comment: One more question. on `ImportExcelCmd_CanExecute` if I put `e.CanExecute = true;` then that method `ImportExcelCmd_CanExecute` is executed twice ... Why ?

Comment: Ideally `CanExecute` should contain only condition to check whether command can be executed or not. If you are putting some extra code then refrain from doing that. Second, command manager internally checks whether command can be executed or not. So, it gets called whenever command manager wants to see if command can be executed or not.

Comment: where do you implement `ImportExcelCmd_CanExecute`? in the codebehind file from the window?

Comment: Yes it needs to be there in code behind file of window.