# Why won't C# WPF RoutedCommands compile?

Tags: c#

```
<Window x:Class="CostelloM_Data_Persistence_v1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ContactMyPeeps(IllegalVersion)" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <RoutedCommand x:Key="Saveas"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.CommandBindings> 
        <CommandBinding Command="Saveas" Executed="Save_As"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="S"
                    Modifiers="Control + Shift"
                    Command="Saveas"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Grid>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Menu>
                <MenuItem Header="File">
                    <MenuItem Command="Save" Header="Save"/>
                    <MenuItem Command="Saveas" Header="Save as" InputGestureText="Ctrl+Shift+S"/>
                    <MenuItem Command="Open" Header="Open"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        <ItemsControl>
                <ComboBox>

                </ComboBox>
        </ItemsControl>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My problem is as follows, the above code will not compile. I have tried saving, cleaning, and rebuilding my visual studio project and still no dice. It says that command converter cannot convert from system.string. Clearly I either misunderstand RoutedCommand and can not use in this way as a custom command. Is there either a way to force RoutedCommand to create a new command, or a different way to use a custom command?

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23028299/commandconverter-cannot-convert-from-system-string-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

You've got typos on several lines, which is most likely giving you a *"CommandConverter cannot convert from System.String"* error because it doesn't recognize the command.

Change this:

```
<CommandBinding Command="Saveas" Executed="Save_As"/>
```

To this:  *(uppercase "A")*

```
<CommandBinding Command="SaveAs" Executed="Save_As"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are defining a command in a resource so you need to tell the binding system that it is in a resource. You need to change several places in the XAML to this

```
Command="{StaticResource Saveas}"
```

However, there are several standard commands pre-defined for you in the `ApplicationCommands` class like Open, Save, and SaveAs. The binding system will automatically try to bind to these but casing is important. This:

```
Command="SaveAs"
```

will bind to the appropriate command defined in `ApplicationCommands`. Then the command defined in the resources becomes unnecessary.